# How can I make my content script run only in the tab that the extension is in?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension runs just in one tab. I'd like my content script to run on any webpage opened in that tab, but only pages opened in that tab.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not directly possible because an extension loads a content script based on url not tabs, due to security policies. You can try this:

- Create a background script and define a function which determines whether you want the content script to load in a specified tab or not (use [tab id](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab) to identify tabs).
- Create a content script that loads on **all urls** (call it
  loader.js).
- From it *call* the background script function (Use  [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to communicate with background script) to determine load your
  main script or not.
- If its a positive you can proceed with loading your main content
  script from loader.js.